# Subscripts in bibtex

Tags: bibtex

I've got references that have math markup in their titles, and I'm having trouble getting bibtex to compile subscript output.  For instance, a title including `$\mathcal{A}_5$` comes out as though it were `$\mathcal{A}\_5$`.  Anyone know how to fix this? What formatting would bibtex prefer?

Comment: Your two things are the same. Please post an example of your BibTeX database.

Comment: You seem to have made a typo in your question, because I would have thought that having `$\mathcal{A}_5$` come out as `$\mathcal{A}_5$` would be exactly what you want, since they are the same.

Comment: Ack, there's supposed to be a backslash there, but the markup ate it.  When I use that in a title, the bibtex output puts in a backslash, and compiles as A_5 visibly.

Comment: When you put the code in backticks (`), markdown parses your question the way I think you intended it.

Comment: What are you using to write your bib files? I used to use jabref and that went crazy sometimes adding in extra pairs of braces and all kinds of stuff...

Answer (score 2):

I don't see your behavior.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{foo.bib}
@misc{foo,
        title = {Math $a_x$},
        author = {Not me},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\cite{foo}
\bibliography{foo}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

Compiling this with `pdflatex`, `bibtex` produces `foo.bbl`:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{foo}
Not me.
\newblock Math $a_x$.

\end{thebibliography}
```

There is no added backslash.

Can you give a similar minimal example that exhibits the behavior you see?

The one thing I can think of to try without seeing your example is to surround your math material in braces `{$a_x$}` in the .bib.

Comment: This is what I was thinking, too. B.t.w, you can embed auxiliary files in minimal examples with the `filecontents` environment.

Answer (score 0):

Define in the beginning of your LaTeX document:

```
\newcommand{\superscript}[1]{\ensuremath{^{\textrm{#1}}}} % superscript
\newcommand{\subscript}[1]{\ensuremath{_{\textrm{#1}}}}   % subscript
```

Then, as bibtex record you may define:

> @article{Duce1995,
>    title={Large CO\subscript{2} change},
>    author={Duce, J.K.},
>    journal={Environmental Science},
>    volume={10},
>    number={5},
>    pages={10--25},
>    year={1995}
>   }

And then you can use this reference with {.}, \citet{.}. I prefer this approach because the usual math mode italicizes super- or subscripts.